# What Regex will match from a specified "trigger" until a space?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex `/\[\w+:/`

Which I use to let me detect when a user types `[something:` into a text field (could be [place: , [info: , [user: , etc...).

I'd like to extend the regex to match characters after the `:` but not beyond a space (and not include the space either). For example,

```
var str = "This is a [place:car a great place to go!";
var matchedStr = str.match(REGEX);
```

The matchedStr value should be `[place:car`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\S` matches anything that is not whitespace, so you could do `\[\w+:\S+` to get your desired match. This includes not just regular space but newlines, tabs, etc too. (which is probably what you want)

You can also simply do a negative character class with a space in: `\[\w+:[^ ]+` (which will *include* tabs/newlines/etc)

Comment: Peter, thank you. You're regex covers exactly what I want, and is succinct. Appreciate your help, and all the great comments to the other answers. /bow

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which chars you want to allow in the string after the ':'.

If you want to match *anything* except whitespace, the following should work:

```
/\[\w+:[^\s]*/
```

If you just want it to match letters, Lee's solution will work.  If you want it to match letters, numbers & underscores, Joseph's answer will do that.

Also, do you want it to succeed if there are no non-space chars after the ':'?

If you want it to match "[aaaa:bbbb", but not "[aaaa:", then you should change the * to a +

```
/\[\w+:[^\s]+/
```

Comment: You can simplify `[^\s]` to `\S`. :)

Comment: Personally, I dislike \S because it's too easy to misread as \s. Yes, [^\s] is three characters longer, but it is much harder to mistake for something that has the opposite meaning.  Just a personal preference.

Comment: Meh. If you can't tell the difference between uppercase and lowercase letters then you're using the wrong font and/or need to visit an optician. :P

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LwR3f/)

```
var str = "This is a [place:car a great place to go!";
var matchedStr = str.match(/\[\w+:\w*/);
```

That works

Comment: This works, and is probably good enough, but does not strictly match the defined criteria of _"match characters after the : but not beyond a space"_ - for example it will not match a hypen, and `[place:flying-car` may be a valid match.

Comment: @Peter Boughton First of all, thanks for your input.  This gets me into trouble a lot but I tend to assume what the poster is after and base my answer off of that.  The example given grabs in simple terms the first word and typically what you would be after are word characters if that's the case.  Since the example is composed of words that's what I assume for better or worse. :P

Comment: Since the OP already seems to know about `\w` then if that is what they wanted they shouldn't need to ask this question? Will have to wait for clarification to find out for sure though.

Comment: @Joseph: If you think the OP should have phrased the question differently, you should say so.  Figuring out the right questions to ask is the very essence of learning.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Actually, to answer Peter, I don't really know much of anything about regex. I really do need to dig in and learn it. The regex I supplied was from a snippet I'd found elsewhere. What could I have added/removed from my question to make it easier to understand? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want a zero-width negative lookahead assertion. See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

```
/\[\w+:(?!\s)/
```

It asserts that the following text does not match its expression, but does not consume any of the input characters (zero-width).

Comment: As you point out, the negative lookahead is a zero-width positional match, which means that to actually match something you need to use it in combination with something else to actually do the consumption of input - such as: `(?:(?!\s).)+` - though of course that's a very long-winded way of doing it when `\S` achieves exactly the same thing in just two characters.

Comment: The OP specified that he did not want the space to be included in the match. Using \W would consume the space and consequently include it.

Comment: Uh, I didn't mention `\W` anywhere? The two code samples in my comment will _not_ include any whitespace characters in the match.

Answer (score 0):

this, maybe

```
var REGEX = /.*(\[[a-z]+:[a-z]+)\s.*/;
var str = "This is a [place:car a great place to go!";
var matchedStr = str.match(REGEX);
var result = matchedStr[1];
alert(result)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/konglie/ExzGz/

Comment: Matching the entire input then extracting a single captured group is generally not a great way of approaching regex problems - in this situation the content outside the group is entirely unnecessary.